# Angularjs 1.4 uses deprecated jquery .attr() function

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am currently using angular 1.4.8 version and is upgrading my jquery to 2.1.4 version. I see that angular.js has reference to .attr(value, val) function which is removed from jquery 1.9. As per the bower.json in latest angular project, it is using jquery 2.1.1
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/bower.json

I am using jQuery migrate plugin to test my code for deprecated functionality and all the warnings are from angular.js. Does anyone know why Angular is still using these deprecated function and how it will affect the project is not fixed?

Comment: `attr` is not removed from jQuery, why do you think so? And Angular doesn't use jQuery (it's not a dependency), it is used in some e2e tests.

Comment: Not deprecated at all ~ http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are referring to the following warning (or similar):

> JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.attr('selected') might use property instead of attribute

which is logged when you use Angular.js along with jQuery-migrate. If so, this warning is about a change of behaviour in jQuery, not a removed function. See the [jQuery migrate warnings list](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/1.x-stable/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryfnattrselected-might-use-property-instead-of-attribute) for information about each warning. In this case:

> **Solution:** Boolean properties should generally not be passed to $().attr at all; replace with $().prop **unless** you truly intend to update the underlying HTML attribute.

I think it's safe to assume that Angular falls into the "unless" condition, so this warning can be ignored.